# VB.NET While Returning String

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net

I have a VB.NET function that is called via AJAX on the front end. The AJAX call passes back some arguments, and the function on the backend generates an HTML table, and returns it to the front end as a string. For example, I would get back something like: `<table><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>`.

My VB function looks like:

```
Public Shared Function MakeTable(arg1, arg2) as String
   ' Do magic
   return myTableInStringFormat
End Function
```

I have run into some issues while using my code and narrowed it down the length of a string coming from the backend. When the string that comes back is greater than 65535 characters it does not make it to the front end. I believe this has to do with the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdzat713.aspx

How do I return back data while avoiding the string character line limit? Line continuation characters seem to be the answer, but I'm not sure how those can be used due to me needing to return a string.

EDIT1: More code. Here is my AJAX postback code, as well as the table appending code:

```
function GetMyTable(arg1, arg2) {
   type: "POST",
   url: myHandler.ashx/MakeTable",
   data: "{'arg1':'" + arg1+ "','arg2':'" + arg2+ "'}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",

   success: function (msg) {
      $("#myTable").empty().append("").append(msg.d);
      },

   error: function () {
      alert("Failed to load ");
   }
   });
   }
```

EDIT2. Here is the backend function the AJAX calls:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function MakeTable(arg1 As String, arg2 As String) As String
   Dim dString As New StringBuilder
   ' Some datareader gets data from database...
    dString.Append("<tr><td>hello</td></tr>")
    return dString.toString()
End Function
```

Comment: The guide is refers to the code, spefically to one line of code, not to the variable's length, this is not your problem. Check if console log of browser give you same error, sometimes it is a security problem because sending code potentially dangerous.

Comment: Not getting any errors. Nothing is ever returned back. Strings under 65535 characters are okay.

Comment: A string can be about 2 billion unicode characters, so its likely not that either.

Comment: First, we need to see a lot more code to be able to help. If you make a break point in the beginning of the above function, what is the error message you get?

Comment: @Caboose So, show us more code. I don't know all your code, but when you get on server side an html code (some char especially) you must set validateRequest="false" but this can be dangerous too.

Comment: I've added some more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Ends up the JSON string size was limited. I added the following to my web.config and all is well!

```
    <scripting>

      <webServices>

        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"></jsonSerialization>

      </webServices>

    </scripting>

  </system.web.extensions>
```